# If I'm using Gmail, can I clean out the space that "Mail Messages" are taking up on my hard drive?

Tags: macos, mail.app, hard-drive, gmail

In looking to make some room on my MacBook Pro's Hard drive, I ran the excellent [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/index.html)

As I expected, movies, my Aperture Archive and other media-intensive files took up a ton of my space. But I was surprised to find that **files that Disk Inventory X categorized as "Mail Message" took up a whopping 22 GB.**

I mostly use Apple Mail as my email client, although I've been giving Sparrow another try lately.  But in either case, other than a legacy MobileMe account that I never use, **Gmail is my mail provider (and storage facility).**

What the heck is stored locally in that size, and can I safely delete it somehow?

(I can't fathom it matters, but I'm running Lion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail is caching your Gmail contents and this is normal for IMAP. See this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/97036/clearing-cache-in-mail-on-snow-leopard) and answers for possible solutions and implications regarding SpotLight search through emails:

- Disable all message caching
- Disable attachment caching

Comment: sincere thanks - I read the SU question, but are my only options really A) disable local storage, or B) store everything I've ever gotten, at 22GB and counting. (Yes, I see that I can save without attachments, but that only partially addresses the issue.)  It seems odd that I can't wither clear it, and save local going forward, or set it to locally save the most recent XX messages, or up to YY days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's probably messages, attachments, indexes, and logs. If you clean them out, you could just try using the online Gmail if it happens again. Otherwise, there's probably a setting for Mail that allows you to choose how many messages to store, and whether to download attachments. (I'm not at my Mac right now)